# Using environment variables for shorter recipes in GNU Make

Tags: gnu-make

I would like recipes in GNU Make to use environment variables instead of command line arguments, to make them shorter, so that I can concentrate better on what changes in each command.  For example, instead of seeing:

```
g++ -g -I/path1 -I/path2 -DFLAG  -Wall -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
```

I would like to see something like:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
```

where `g++` would read include directories and everything else from environment variables.  Therefore, instead of using this:

```
compile.cxx = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c

%.o: %.cpp
    $(compile.cxx) $< -o $@
```

I am using this:

```
compile.cxx = CPATH="$(CPATH)" LIBRARY_PATH="$(LIBRARY_PATH)" bash -c $(CXX) -c

%.o: %.cpp
    $(compile.cxx) $< -o $@
```

But I get this output:

```
CPATH="irrelevant" LIBRARY_PATH="irrelevant" bash -c g++ -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

Hence, it seems that `g++` does not receive its arguments.

I am also open to alternatives that achieve a similar effect (that is: short recipes).

Comment: I don't think you need the `bash -c` to pass command line arguments for a command, but I further don't think that these `CXXFLAGS` variables are honoured by the compiler commands themselves. The variables are just a standard way to tune Makefiles from the environment. To debug `bash -c` use and `-x` option `bash -x -c` to see what is called. But anyway you need to quote the argument, though the manual page `bash(1)` seems to say something else.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to quote the argument to `-c` and still write a rule that takes a target as an argument.  Anyway, thank you for making me realize that GCC honours other environment variables (I have fixed my question to reflect this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a so-called compiler response file which is very common in [MS toolchains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3te4xt0y(v=vs.140).aspx).  Apparently recent versions of GCC also support it (see [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)).

```
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS = -I/path1 -I/path2 -DFLAG
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall
CXXOPTS = $(CURDIR)/cxx.opts

%.o: %.cpp $(CXXOPTS)
        $(CXX) @$(CXXOPTS) -c -o $@ $<

$(CXXOPTS):
        echo "$(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)" >$@

clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f $(CXXOPTS)
```

Sample session:

```
$ touch a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
$ make a.o b.o c.o
echo "-I/path1 -I/path2 -DFLAG -g -Wall" >cxx.opts
g++ @cxx.opts -c -o a.o a.cpp
g++ @cxx.opts -c -o b.o b.cpp
g++ @cxx.opts -c -o c.o c.cpp
$ make clean
rm -f *.o
rm -f cxx.opts
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no complete answer but a first hint and it looks quite ugly

```
v:=bash -x -c "
all:
    $vls -l"
```

but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simly that bash -c only takes 1 arg, and quite simply you dont need it. Try:

```
compile.cxx = CPATH="$(CPATH)" LIBRARY_PATH="$(LIBRARY_PATH)" $(CXX) -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Some makefiles are set up to print one command and execute a different command, through the use of macros that can be complex. Here's a simple way of doing it:

```
ifeq(debug,)
cc = $(CC) $(CFLAGS)
else
cc = @cc () { echo "\$$(CC) $<"; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) "$$@" }; cc
endif

foo.o: foo.c
        $(cc) $<
```

If the variable `debug` has a non-empty value, this snippet prints the command normally. Otherwise this snippet hides the command (the command line ends up starting with `@`) and prints a substituted, simpler command before executing the actual command.

I presented a very simple example. Several more complex variants exist in different projects. For example the Linux kernel uses a rather advanced scheme.

I don't recommend that because they make it harder to debug makefiles. Something fails due to a bad include path or something, and the make output won't tell you. Sophisticated schemes that log whole commands to a file and show an abbreviated command on the terminal are ok.

To make the output of make more readable, consider [colormake](https://github.com/pagekite/Colormake) instead.